# How to insert record into database using checkbox

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, sqlalchemy

My goal is to add a new record into database using Tkinter's checkbox. For example if you choose one of the checkbox's value and type name of element and its price then it will be inserted into database.

I've built a window which contains several checkbox's values, and entry label for the name of element and price. Also, I tried to write a function which inserting data into my database, but records don't appear in the database.

```
edited_equipment = StringVar()
edited_price = IntVar()

def alter_eqiupment():
    master = Tk()
    master.geometry("150x350")

    navigation_var = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(master, text="navigation", 
    variable=navigation_var).grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky=W)
    interior_var = IntVar()

    Checkbutton(master, text="interior", variable=interior_var).grid(row=1, 
    column = 0, sticky=W)
    wheels_var = IntVar()

    Checkbutton(master, text="wheels", variable=wheels_var).grid(row=2, 
    column = 0, sticky=W)
    audio_var = IntVar()

    Checkbutton(master, text="audio", variable=audio_var).grid(row=3, 
    column = 0, sticky=W)
    upholstery_var = IntVar()

    Checkbutton(master, text="upholstery", 
    variable=upholstery_var).grid(row=4, column = 0, sticky=W)
    sensor_var = IntVar()

    Checkbutton(master, text="sensor", variable=sensor_var).grid(row=5, 
    column = 0, sticky=W)

    Label(master, text = "name", font = ('',13),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky 
    = W)
    Entry(master, textvariable = edited_equipment, bd = 3,font = 
    ('',10)).grid(row=7,column=0)

    Label(master, text = "price", font = ('',13),pady=5,padx=5).grid(sticky 
    = W)
    Entry(master, textvariable = edited_price, bd = 3,font = 
    ('',10)).grid(row=9,column=0)


    def insert_edited():
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Baza_trzecia.db')
            with conn:
                    cur = conn.cursor()
                    if navigation_var.get() == 1:
                            cur.execute('insert into navigation (name, 
                            price) values (?,?)', ((edited_equipment), 
                            (edited_price))      
                            conn.commit()

                    # the same if statements for other elements


    Button(master, text = ' Save ',bd = 3 ,font = ('',12),padx=10,pady=10, 
    command = insert_edited).grid()


    mainloop()
```

Here's my class for navigation table, written in SQLAlchemy:

```
class Navigations(Base):
    __tablename__ = "navigation"

    id_navigation = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    navigation_name = Column(String)
    price = Column(Integer)
    sqlite_autoincrement=True

    def __init__(self, navigation_name, price):
        self.navigation_name = navigation_name
        self.price = price
```

Comment: `insert_edited` contains some syntax errors as well, such as a non-triple-quoted string spanning multiple lines, and missing bracket at the end of `cur.execute` call. Copy paste errors as well?

Comment: Yes, there was a missing bracket. I don't know why the compiler doesn't return any error before and now after correction. What do you think about `if navigation_var.get() == 1:`. Can you show me a different type of solution?

Comment: `edited_equipment` and `edited_price` in `(edited_equipment), (edited_price)` is almost certainly not what you think it is. Have you examined the value to confirm that what you're trying to insert is what you think it is?

Comment: OK, something works! It is inserting into the database but it is "empty string". In the database, I can see empty record (only with id). But unfortunately, I have also a problem with the value of checkboxes. They always return zero, even if they were pressed (I tested inserting into the database with `if navigation_var.get() == 0`: I reorganize my code into OOP. Please look at this, and advice me, I've spent the whole day trying to deal with it... Here's my full code. https://pastebin.com/XRrDTErV

Comment: Since `edited_equipment` and `edited_price` are `StringVar` and `IntVar` respectively, the content of them should be retrieved via `.get()` and not reference them directly.

Comment: *"What do you think about if navigation_var.get() == 1:"*: Do you realy want to save  the same `name`/`price` into multiple `table`?

Comment: No, for every element I will make another if statement. But actually, my checkboxes still don't work as I want to.

Comment: *"No, for every element I will make another if statement."*: That's not my Question. Using `Checkbox`'es allows to **check** multiple, using `Radiobutton` or `OptionMenu` allows **only one** and no need for multiple `if statements`